# Concerns with managing JAX WS artifacts

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm developing an application that makes heavy use of web services. I will be developing both the client and server ends of this application. I'd like to use JAX WS (which I am new to), because it seems to be the future for web services for Java, but I have a number of concerns related to the artifacts. None of these concerns is a deal-breaker, but collectively, JAX WS seems to create a lot of inconvenience. I'm new to JAX WS, so perhaps there are things I am unaware of that would alleviate my concerns.

Here are my concerns:

1. I anticipate having a fairly large number of POJOs that are passed between client and server (for lack of a better term, I'll call these transport objects). I would like to include documentation and business logic in these objects (for starters, equals, hashcode, toString). If I have business logic in these classes, then I cannot use wsimport to create the annotations for them, and I have to manage those by hand. Seems cumbersome and error-prone.
2. I have a choice of having the build system create artifacts, or having developers create artifacts and check them into source control. If artifacts are produced by the build system, then whenever a member of the team updates an API, everyone must generate artifacts in their own development environments. If artifacts are produced by developers and checked into source control, any time a member of the team renames or deletes an API, he must remember to delete wrapper artifacts. Either approach seems to be cumbersome. What's the best practice here?
3. wsimport creates all the artifacts in the same package. I will be creating multiple services, and I will have some transport objects that are shared, and therefore I need to wsimport all my services into the same package. If two services have an API with the same name, the wrapper artifacts will collide.
4. I anticipate having at least a hundred API's in my services. This means at least 200 wrapper classes. Seems like a huge amount of clutter. Lots and lots of classes that are of no interest for development. To make matters worse, these wrapper classes will reside in the same package as the transport objects, which will be some of the most highly-used classes in my system. Signal to noise ratio is very low for the most important package in my system.

Any pointers anyone can give me to ease development of my application would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over both the client and the server you don't really have to generate the client with `wsimport`. I currently do it as follows: One project defines the API for the web service. The API consists of the interface and all classes of the "transfer objects". Another project implements the service. You can now distribute the API to the client who can now use the service and may leverage all your additional business methods.

Assuming `ServiceInterface` is your service interface a client might look like this:

```
Service s = Service.create(
        new URL("http://example.com/your_service?wsdl"),
        new QName("http://example.com/your_namespace", "YourServiceName"));
ServiceInterface yourService = s.getPort(
        new QName("http://example.com/your_namespace", "YourPortName"),
        ServiceInterface.class);
```

And just like that you have a service client. That way you can use all your methods (1), you have full control over your packages (3) and you don't have any wrapper classes lying around as they are all generated at runtime (4). I think (2) is solved by this as well.

Your question is quite large so if I fail to address a point sufficiently, leave a comment and I try to get into more detail.

Comment: I've done a lot of research, and never came across anything that suggested that the client artifacts could be created at runtime. That is great and pretty much resolves all of my concerns.

Comment: In my opinion Enterprise Java (I count web services to enterprise even though it's available in Java SE as well) can be really daunting in its complexity. What you just experienced happens to me all the time as well. ;)

Comment: @musiKk, will s.getPort(QName) will work? Don't we have to provide the ServiceInterface.class along with it ? I added that too, but still it is not working. One more doubt, when these wrapper class gets created  every time on the fly won't it affect performance ?

Comment: @kaushik: You're right, the class argument was missing. Regarding performance: You only have to create the port once and use it throughout the lifetime of your application.

Comment: @musiKk, In my eclipse it is showing every time a message INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class org.kwa.www.jaxws.GetConsumerLedger and in my build folder that class does not exist. So every time those classes gets created isn't it ?